# Access variables from the global scope within a closure

Tags: php, scope, closures

**I am well aware that globals are evil and this is an issue I will deal with later**. It's not my codebase, but I've been assigned some cleaning up tasks.

Trying to smarten up a codebase, I decided to implement simple routing by using a package known as [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/usage/processing-requests.html) - I've worked with it before and it has worked fine for my purposes.

Now, the codebase is using a large amount of variables declared in the global scope. Usually, these variables are then fetched by using the `global`keyword. But for some reason, this doesn't work when I'm working inside a closure.

Consider this simple routing example:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map('GET', '/shops/[i:id]', function($id) {

    $_GET['shop_id'] = $id;
    require 'go_to_shop.php';
});

$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
}
```

This calls my closure that sets a variable and requires a file.

This produces an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in
>   /vagrant/Core/CampaignHandler.php on line 71

Now, the code being called doing this is the following (line 70-71):

```
// Inside a method
global $serviceContainer;
$dispatcher = $serviceContainer->get("dispatcher");
```

The `$serviceContainer` is being declared by including a file early on:

```
$serviceContainer = new ServiceContainer();
$serviceContainer->set("dispatcher", new EventDispatcher());
```

Basically, if I move the contents of the closure outside of the closure, everything works perfectly - but as soon as I'm doing it from inside the closure, all variables accessed via the global scope is empty - and I have no idea as to why.

I've tried using `use` on the closure, this didn't work either.

I'm mostly looking for an explanation rather than a solution.

Comment: Is the file where `$serviceContainer` is being declared included *within a function*...?

Comment: @deceze, no, it's just a file that's included and `$serviceContainer`resides in the global variable scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globals are evil for a reason. You get the error because the global is not initialized at the time when function is being called. The mess of `global`s and `require`s is the exact issue and you are already trying to deal with it.

There is no problem to use globals in closure per se. This example works perfectly fine:

global.php:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function bar() { return 'bar';}
}

$foo = new Foo;
```

test.php:

```
<?php
require 'global.php';

$test = function($param) {
    global $foo;
    echo $param, $foo->bar();
}

call_user_func_array($test, ['baz']);
```

so `php test.php` outputs `bazbar`;

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the `$serviceContainer` variable does not exist in the global scope, but the question leaves that part out.

Can't you pass the container to the anonymous function using a `use( $serviceContainer )` statement? That'd be a far cleaner solution then having to rely on globals.

```
function($id) use( $serviceContainer ) {

   $_GET['shop_id'] = $id;
   require 'go_to_shop.php';
}
```

Off-topic: not sure what you're doing with that id variable later on and why you're putting it back into the $_GET variable like that, but please be careful.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the manual for anonymus functions–also known as closures, which in real are objects.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Theses callables have specific functions for extending their scopes.

See: **Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope**.

```
$message = 'hello';

// No "use"
$example = function () {
  var_dump($message);
};
$example();

// Inherit $message
$example = function () use ($message) {
  var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

Sure you want to assign a value to the $_GET global var?

```
$_GET['shop_id'] = $id;
```

The shop ID in your route you can extract from altorouter parameters. (See documentation.)

```
$router->map( 'GET', '/', function() { .. }, 'home' );

// assuming current request url = '/'
$match = $router->match();

/*
array(3) { 
  ["target"]    => object(Closure)#2 (0) { } 
  ["params"]    => array(0) { } 
  ["name"]  => 'home' 
}
*/
```

Or if you want to store an ID for a session use $_COOKIES or $_SESSION global variables.